# Following code not working in LaTeX : $\{f^'_n\}$

Tags: math-mode

Why does the following code does'nt work when i am using PDFLaTeX or just LaTeX ? I tried it in different editors as well.

This is the code

```
 $\{f^'_n\}$
```

Surprisingly it works on Math.SE site

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In math mode, `'` is active and is defined as `^\prime`. Thus you should not use `^'`: just `'` will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\{f'_n\}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, almost: Some trick is done (at least in LaTeX) to allow human-readable input such as `$f''(x)$`; if `'` simply meant `^\prime` this would lead to "double superscript" error.

Comment: @Villemoes: An `'` active does not expand directly to `^\prime` but to some look-ahead code that deals with this case.

Comment: As an aside, I tried (once) to get `^'` style input working in `unicode-math`, but it ended up breaking the syntax in other places `:(`